# Count amount of String occurrences and comparisons (KMP)

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I'm trying to count the amount of pattern occurrences and needed comparisons (called matches in the code below), using search algorithm **KMP**.

I've tried doing the following:

```
public class KMP {

    private String pat;
    private int[][] dfa;
    private static int match;
    private static int count;

    public KMP(String pat) {
        // Build DFA from pattern.      
        this.pat = pat;
        int M = pat.length();
        int R = 256;
        dfa = new int[R][M];
        dfa[pat.charAt(0)][0] = 1;
        for (int X = 0, j = 1; j < M; j++) {
            // Compute dfa[][j].         
            for (int c = 0; c < R; c++) {
                dfa[c][j] = dfa[c][X];           // Copy mismatch cases.        
                dfa[pat.charAt(j)][j] = j + 1;   // Set match case.    
                X = dfa[pat.charAt(j)][X];       // Update restart state.   
            }
        }
    }

    public int search(String txt) {
        // Simulate operation of DFA on txt.    
        int i, j, N = txt.length(), M = pat.length();
        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < N && j < M; i++) {
            j = dfa[txt.charAt(i)][j];
        }
        if (j == M) {
            return i - M; // found (hit end of pattern)  
        } else {
            return N;     // not found (hit end of text)  
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String pat = "babba";
        String txt = "aaaaaaaaaaaabbaaababbaaaaababbaaaa";
        int lastIndex = 0;

        KMP kmp = new KMP(pat);
        int offset = kmp.search(txt);

        System.out.println("text:    " + txt);
        System.out.print("pattern: ");

        while (lastIndex != txt.length()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < offset; i++) {
                lastIndex++;
                match++;
            }
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(pat);
        System.out.println("count:   " + count);
        System.out.println("match:   " + match);
    }
}
```

My code works just fine when compiling it like this, but when I change the `String txt` attribute to something like `aaaaaaaaaaaabbaaababbaaaaababbaaaababba`, It gives me an unexpected, negative count value (also, it takes about 30 seconds to actually run the code).

I'm trying to find a better solution of counting the occurrences and I'd also like to know what's wrong with my code, since it only works in some cases.

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, yes, I did. My program compiles, but it takes a long time and it gives an incorrect value for count.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is your loop condition.

```
while (lastIndex != txt.length())
```

Your problem string has a length of 38 and an offset of 17.
Each for-loop `lastIndex` is increment by 17.
After the third for-loop it has the value 51.
That fulfills the condition and the loop continues.
It ends only after probably several int overflows which causes the negative count value.

Also you can't count the occurences like that.
`kmp.search()` only returns the start position of the first occurence of the pattern.
For example

```
String txt = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaababbaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
```

Your code returns `count = 2`.

A solution would be to split the string after each search and then search the substring after the pattern.

```
KMP kmp = new KMP(pat);
int offset = kmp.search(txt);
while (offset != txt.length()) {
    count++;
    txt = txt.substring(offset+pat.length());
    offset = kmp.search(txt);
}
System.out.println("count:   " + count);
```

Edit: The code above only works for non overlapping patterns.

```
txt = txt.substring(offset+at.length());
```

needs to be changed to

```
txt = txt.substring(offset+1);
```

if there is an overlap.

Comment: Works perfectly! Although, I'm also trying to count the amount of performed matches.

Comment: @MJM What do you mean by matches? Using the algorithm above `search()` will look at each position of the input string.

Comment: The amount of character comparisons the algorithm performs.

Comment: Zero. There is no real character comparison since you are only using the character values to move through the dfa matrix.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I misunderstood. It's the operation count (defined as number of arithmetic operations) of the algorithm.